# How to convert byte[] to string in c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

To prevent concurrency i have included a field version which is a Timestamps type. I don't no how to convert version value  to string. Please help me to solve this problem.

```
using (MMP2012Entities context = new MMP2012Entities())
{
    var res = (from i in context.LIN_Laundry_Issues
    join sub in context.LIN_Laundry_Iss_Sub on i.Issue_Number equals sub.Issue_Number
    join it in context.MMP_Items on sub.Item_Id equals it.id
    where i.Issue_Number==id && i.Hospital_Id==hospid && sub.Status_ind==1
    select new Laundry_IssueRecieptList
    {
        Issue_Date = i.Issue_Date,
        Collected_By = i.Collected_By,
        Authorised_By = i.Authorised_By,
        Laundry_Id = i.Laundry_Id,
        Item_Id = sub.Item_Id,
        Item_name = it.Name,
        Qty_Issued = sub.Qty_Issued,
        Rate = sub.Rate,
        Issue_Number=i.Issue_Number,
        subissueid=sub.Laundry_Trans_Sub_Id,
        Status_ind=sub.Status_ind,
        version=sub.Version
    }).ToList();
    return res;
}
```

Comment: How that `byte[]` was created?

Comment: It makes zero sense to turn that into a string because it is not a string. At best you can generate a hex representation, but that is it. Timestamps are not timestamps, tehy are a binary version number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this function:

```
private string ByteArrayToString(byte[] ba)
{
    StringBuilder hex = new StringBuilder(ba.Length * 2);
    foreach (byte b in ba) {
        hex.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
    }

    return hex.ToString();
}
```

and reverse as

```
private byte[] StringToByteArray(string hexString)
{
    int length = hexString.Length;
    int upperBound = length / 2;
    if (length % 2 == 0) {
        upperBound -= 1;
    } else {
        hexString = "0" + hexString;
    }
    byte[] bytes = new byte[upperBound + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i <= upperBound; i++) {
        bytes[i] = Convert.ToByte(hexString.Substring(i * 2, 2), 16);
    }

    return bytes;
}
```

Comment: Note this will have to happen after the `IQueryable` bits.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're working with UTF8 (if not use the correct object under System.Text.Encoding.XXX.GetString(bytes);

```
string str = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);
```

Comment: then how to revert this str to byte[]. Because i have compare in where condition

Comment: YOu do not. This is a terrible idea also becaause a timestamp is NOT A STRING - you amy get all kinds of symbols there that are hard to even watch. A hex string would be better.

Comment: I'm answering the question asked in the title.

Comment: To get bytes from the string, use the following method: byte[] bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(str);

Answer (score 0):

```
        public static string TimestampToString(this System.Data.Linq.Binary binary)

        {
            byte[] binarybytes = binary.ToArray();

            string result = "";
            foreach (byte b in binarybytes)
           {
                result += b.ToString() + "|";
            }
            result = result.Substring(0, result.Length - 1);
            return result;
       }

        public static System.Data.Linq.Binary StringToTimestamp(this string s)
        {
            string[] arr = s.Split('|');
            byte[] result = new byte[arr.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++)
            {
                result[i] = Convert.ToByte(arr[i]);
            }
            return result;
        }
```