# c# concatenate byte[] and get string result

Tags: c#, arrays, bytecode, concatenation, bitconverter

I came across one requirement, in which i have **`system.byte[]`** value coming from database.
 Now i need to get string value from that **`bye[]`** values. 
I am iterating **`datatable`** values using **`datarow`**.
 There are so many columns coming with **`system.byte[]`** value. *How can i check **`system.byte[]`** value and convert it into string show as a result?*

Comment: If i summarize you need to convert byte array to string? And I suppose this is ASP.NEt? visit and check my function might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27498856/how-to-convert-byte-to-string-in-c-sharp/27498904#27498904

Comment: possible duplicate of [byte\[\] to hex string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/623104/byte-to-hex-string)

Comment: How is the text encoded in those bytes? You need to know that before you can correctly decode the bytes into text. Is it UTF8? UTF16? Ascii? etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are asking two questions here : "How to concate" and "How to convert".

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        byte[] bytes1 = { 97, 98, 99, 100 };
        byte[] bytes2 = { 49, 50, 51, 52 };

        // concat
        byte[] bytes = bytes1.Concat(bytes2).ToArray();
        // convert
        string bytesAsString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes);

        Console.WriteLine(bytesAsString);

    }
}
```

[Demo DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/WJw2jj)